# How to properly handle UTF-8 in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, encoding, utf-8, encodeuricomponent

I'm trying to get our chat system to support UTF-8, but I'm failing. If, on the client side, I send the following message, passed through `encodeURIComponent`:

- îûôó

And put this on the PHP end:

```
error_log(print_r(array(
    $_POST['message'],
    urldecode($_POST['message']),
    rawurldecode($_POST['message']),
    utf8_decode($_POST['message']),
    utf8_decode(urldecode($_POST['message'])),
    utf8_decode(rawurldecode($_POST['message']))
), true));
```

This is the output in my error log:

```
Array
(
    [0] => %C3%AE%C3%BB%C3%B4%C3%B3
    [1] => Ã®Ã»Ã´Ã³
    [2] => Ã®Ã»Ã´Ã³
    [3] => %C3%AE%C3%BB%C3%B4%C3%B3
    [4] => îûôó
    [5] => îûôó
)
```

So all is fine. However, if I use these, both copied from Wikipedia (Russian language and Japanese language pages, respectively):

- русский язык
- 日本語

It all goes to hell!

```
Array
(
    [0] => %D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA
    [1] => Ñ€ÑƒÑÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹ ÑÐ·Ñ‹Ðº
    [2] => Ñ€ÑƒÑÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹ ÑÐ·Ñ‹Ðº
    [3] => %D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA
    [4] => ??????? ????
    [5] => ??????? ????
)
Array
(
    [0] => %E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E
    [1] => æ—¥æœ¬èªž
    [2] => æ—¥æœ¬èªž
    [3] => %E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E
    [4] => ???
    [5] => ???
)
```

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: just in case of: maybe your log file encoding & displaying font does not handle utf8? If you put japanese & russian directly on the PHP side does it work? Are you sure content is broken on javascript sending side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$_POST['message'], => [0] => %C3%AE%C3%BB%C3%B4%C3%B3
```

You have over-URL-encoded your input. The GET/POST/REQUEST superglobals have already taken care of URL-decoding input strings where necessary, you should not need to URL-decode them manually.

Have a look at whatever is causing this request (an XMLHttpRequest?) and remove the excess call to `encodeURIComponent()`. For example if you are using jQuery `ajax()` and passing in POST-data as an object, jQuery will be calling `encodeURIComponent()` for you and you don't need to do it yourself as well.

```
urldecode($_POST['message']), => Ã®Ã»Ã´Ã³
```

This is UTF-8 misinterpreted as Windows code page 1252 (Western European, similar to ISO-8859-1).

Most likely you have successfully saved UTF-8 bytes to your log file, but whatever you're reading the log file in doesn't realise that it should be rendered as UTF-8.

```
utf8_decode(urldecode($_POST['message'])), => îûôó
```

This only works because the characters you have used to test it also exist in code page 1252. `utf8_decode` is misleadingly named; what it actually does is convert a UTF-8 byte sequence to an ISO-8859-1 byte sequence that would represent the same string. You usually want to work in UTF-8 and not ISO-8859-1 so you should in general avoid utf8_decode.

```
русский язык => ??????? ????
```

Understandable: Cyrillic characters don't exist in code page 1252.

Assuming you are sending your error_log output to a file, and trying to read the file, stick with the plain UTF-8 bytes, and read your logs in a decent text editor that lets you see and choose the encoding; ideally a modern one that defaults to UTF-8. Alternatively you can persuade Notepad to read a Unicode file by saving as UTF-16 or UTF-8 and including a Byte Order Mark at the start. (It's kind of wrong to include a BOM in a UTF-8 file, but lots of tools in the Microsoft world do it.)

Comment: You, sir, are brilliant. Every bit of this answer was spot on :) Got it working, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Go UTF8 across the whole stack:

- Database tables
- Database connection
- PHP default character set setting
- String functions

### Database Tables:

Set the db collation to `utf8_unicode_ci`.
Set all text/varchar fields to `utf8_unicode_ci`.
Set the database connection to be UTF-8 by executing the following query:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

### PHP Charset

Use:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
```

### PHP String Functions

Some PHP string functions aren't binary safe and so you need to use the mb_* equivalents.

e.g. `mb_strlen` instead of `strlen`

### HTML:

Set the charset with a meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: don't repeat the same answer ... there are already tons of answer like this

Comment: Then why don't you link Aistina to one of those answers? In the meantime, I'll provide a bit of help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279#279279